How to mark captcha as image using node js playwright?
i was try to bypass captcha but the captcha use image to text. i try use capmonster and capsolver but both of them don't know that the image is captcha, and i have to mark it as captcha to tell them
i try to bypass captcha and i wish i can bypass it
this is the code i already try it :
i call this code in my main script :
var caprest = capmonster.imageToText();


then this is the module:
const createTask = async (clientKey, base64Image) => {
  const response = await axios.post('https://api.capmonster.cloud/createTask', {
    clientKey: clientKey,
    task: {
      type: 'ImageToTextTask',
      body: base64Image,
    },
  });
  return response.data.taskId;
};

const getTaskResult = async (clientKey, taskId) => {
  while (true) {
    const response = await axios.post('https://api.capmonster.cloud/getTaskResult', {
      clientKey: clientKey,
      taskId: taskId,
    });
    const result = response.data;
    if (result.status === 'ready') {
      return result.solution.text;
    } else {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    }
  }
};

const imageToText = async (api) => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://example.com/captcha/image/publish_new');
  const imageUrl = response.data; 

  const imageResponse = await axios.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
  const base64Image = Buffer.from(imageResponse.data, 'binary').toString('base64');

  const taskId = await createTask(api, base64Image);
  return await getTaskResult(api, taskId);
};


please provide more details. What do you get? What do you try to achieve?
